# When does file from local system is moved to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop, so please excuse me if my questions are trivial.

- Is local file system is different than HDFS.
- While creating a mapreduce program, we file input file path using fileinputformat.addInputPath() function. Does it split that data into multiple data node and also perform inputsplits as well? If yes, how long this data will stay in datanodes? And can we write mapreduce program to the existing data in HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

1：`HDFS` is actually a solution to distributed storage, and there will be more storage ceilings and backup problems in localized storage space. `HDFS` is the server cluster storage resource as a whole, through the `nameNode` storage directory and block information management, `dataNode` is responsible for the block storage container. `HDFS` can be regarded as a higher level abstract localized storage, and it can be understood by solving the core problem of distributed storage.

2：if  we  use  `hadoop fileinputformat`  ,  first  it create an `open （）` method  to  `filesystem`   and  get connection to `namenode`   to  get location messages  return  those message  to client .  then  create  a  `fsdatainputstream`  to read from different nodes  one by one ..    at the end  close  the   `fsdatainputstream`

if  we put  data  into hdfs the client  the data  will be split  into multiple  data  and storged  in different  machine   (bigger than 128M [64M])
 Data persistence is stored on the hard disk

SO  if  your  file  is much bigger beyond the pressure of Common server   &  need Distributed computing  you can use  HDFS

Answer (score 0):

HDFS is *not* your local filesystem - it is a *distributed file system*. This means your dataset can be larger than the maximum storage capacity of a single machine in your cluster. HDFS by default uses a block size of 64 MB. Each block is replicated to at least 3 other nodes in the cluster to account for redundancies (such as node failure). So with HDFS, you can think of your entire cluster as one large file system.

When you write a MapReduce program and set your input path, it will try to locate that path on the HDFS. The input is then automatically divided up into what is known as *input splits* - fixed size partitions containing multiple records from your input file. A `Mapper` is created for each of these splits. Next, the `map` function (which you define) is applied to each record within each split, and the output generated is stored in the local filesystem of the node where `map` function ran from. The `Reducer` then copies this output file to its node and applies the `reduce` function.  In the case of a runtime error when executing `map` and the task fails, Hadoop will have the same mapper task run on another node and have the reducer copy that output.

The reducers use the outputs generated from all the mapper tasks, so by this point, the reducers are not concerned with the input splits that was fed to the mappers.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping answers as per the questions:

**HDFS vs local filesystem**

Yes, `HDFS` and local file system are different. `HDFS` is a `Java`-based file system that is a layer above a native filesystem (like `ext3`). It is designed to be distributed, scalable and fault-tolerant.

**How long do data nodes keep data?**

When data is ingested into HDFS, it is split into blocks, replicated 3 times (by default) and distributed throughout the cluster data nodes. This process is all done automatically. This data will stay in the data nodes till it is deleted and finally purged from trash.

**InputSplit calculation**

[FileInputFormat.addInputPath()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html#addInputPath) specifies the HDFS file or directory from which files should be read and sent to mappers for processing. Before this point is reached, the data should already be available in HDFS, since it is now attempting to be processed. So the data files themselves have been split into blocks and replicated throughout the data nodes. The mapping of files, their blocks and which nodes they reside on - this is maintained by a master node called the `NameNode`.

Now, based on the input path specified by this API, `Hadoop` will calculate the number of InputSplits required for processing the file/s. Calculation of InputSplits is done at the start of the job by the `MapReduce` framework. Each InputSplit then gets processed by a mapper. This all happens automatically when the job runs.

**MapReduce on existing data**

Yes, MapReduce program can run on existing data in HDFS.